# Migrating files with descriptions

Tags: entities, migrations

I'm currently migrating PDF files into a content type. I would like to know how to populate the file information description field with a more meaningful link (e.g. give a description to each imported file).

```
$arguments = MigrateFileFieldHandler::arguments(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_migrate').'/docs', 'file_copy', FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);  

$this->addFieldMapping('field_publication_download', 'files')
  ->arguments($arguments);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a link](http://drupalcode.org/project/migrate.git/blob/f5ac11d829010646e207d0683bb5fc1c553f93cb:/plugins/destinations/fields.inc#l595) that shows all the arguments you can pass to `MigrateFileFieldHandler`. As you can see description is the 7th argument.

If you don't want to specify any of the arguments before `description`, you still have to pass `NULL` to them e.g.:

```
$arguments = MigrateFileFieldHandler::arguments(
  drupal_get_path('module', 'my_migrate').'/docs', 
  'file_copy', 
  FILE_EXISTS_RENAME, 
  NULL, 
  NULL, 
  NULL, 
  array('source_field' => 'migrate_source_description_field'), //Can also pass a string here
);
```

Comment: Nice thanks.  It was a csv migration so instead i used preparerow

Comment: @rix, if this is useful to you consider marking it as an answer for the rest of the community!