# Migrate Multi-value Filefield (File Description)

Tags: migrations

Posted this here as well http://drupal.org/node/1943324

I am trying to migrate multi-value file-fields.
I checked out the wine.inc but the sample provided doesn't work for me.
I tried to use JSON-encoded arrays that didn't work either and i read somewhere that method is now obsolete.

How to do this?

Here's what i have:

`$this->addFieldMapping('field_case_file_upload', 'file_upload_url');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_case_file_upload:description', 'file_upload_title');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_case_file_upload:destination_dir')
             ->defaultValue('public://pdfs/sun_files');`

```
    public function prepareRow($current_row) {
        $result = db_select('tbl_myfiles', 'f')
                  ->fields('f', array('file_upload_url', 'file_upload_filepath', 'file_upload_title'))
                  ->condition('content_id',$current_row->content_id)
                  ->condition('f.file_upload_url', '%pdf%', 'LIKE')
                  ->execute();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
              $current_row->file_upload_url[] = $row->file_upload_url;
              $current_row->file_upload_filepath[] = $row->file_upload_filepath;
              $current_row->file_upload_title[] = $row->file_upload_title;
        return TRUE;
         }  
           }
```

I am sure im not doing something right. Can someone cool please point me in the right direction? :)

I have tried the solution provided here but still can't get the file_descripton in [Migrating files with descriptions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14969/migrating-files-with-descriptions)

Comment: Maybe this thread helps ( http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54810/migrating-multiple-files-in-a-node ) This guy is migrating a node with files attached. You might have to 'filter' out the node-parts.